# Python append to a .txt

Tags: python, append

Hi im still learning python and currently trying to write some data to a txt file. I'm having issues with adding more than 1 persons details.I can the first persons details and it works fine but when I choose to add another persons set of details I get the following error.

```
line 58, in <module>
    datalist.append(first)
AttributeError: 'map' object has no attribute 'append'
```

any help would be appreciated, I did check other similar questions but couldn't work it out.

```
genderlist=["M", "F",]
moredata="Y"

datalist=[]
while (moredata=="Y" or moredata== "y"):

    datafile = open ("peSchool.text", "a+")
    first=input( "enter first name ")
    while not first.isalpha():
        print (" name should be alphabetic")
        first=input("enter first name ")
    second=input("surname ")
    while not second.isalpha():
        print (" surname should be alphabetic")
        second=input("enter surname ")
    postcode=input("postcode ")
    gender=input("enter gender ")
    gender=gender.upper()
    while gender not in genderlist:
        print ("gender should be M, F ")
        gender = input("Gender ")
        gender = gender.upper() 
    age=input("enter age ")
    while int(age) not in range(11,15):
        print(" age must be betwwen 11 and 15 ")
        age=input("enter age ")
    if int(age) ==11:
        group="1"
    elif int(age) ==12:
        group="2"
    elif int(age) ==13:
        group="3"
    else:
        group="4"


    unit=int(input("enter SATS units"))
    while int(unit) not in range(4,9):
        print(" SATS must be between 4 - 8 ")
        unit=input("enter SATS units")
    if int(unit) ==4:
        if gender=="M":
            unit = "Blake House"
        elif gender=="F":
            unit = "Woolfe House"
    elif int(unit) in range (5,6):
        if gender=="M":
            unit = "Harrison House"
        elif gender=="F":
            unit = "Gordon House"
    else:
        unit = "Jackson House"

    datalist.append(first)
    datalist.append(second)
    datalist.append(postcode)
    datalist.append(gender)
    datalist.append(age)
    datalist.append(unit)

    print (datalist.count)
    datalist = map(str, datalist)
    line = ",".join(datalist)
    datafile.writelines(line + "\n")





    print("First Name", first, "Surname", second, "Postcode", postcode, "Gender", gender, "Age", age, "house", unit, "Science Group ", group,)
    datafile.close()
    moredata=input("more students y/n ")
    moredata = moredata.upper()
```

Comment: In python 3, map doesn't return a list, it returns a `map` object.  Do `datalist = list(map(str, datalist))` to get the data into a list.

Comment: Don't you want to reset `datalist` after writing it contents to the data file anyway?

Comment: thanks will give that a go. I want to keep adding each person to a new line

Comment: unrelated:  `gender = input("enter gender ").upper()`, `group=min(int(input("enter age "))-10,4)` (be careful with missinputs though && check for group in [1,2,3,4]

Comment: If you don't reset `datalist`, each line is going to consist of every line that precedes it. `datalist = []` should be the first line after the `while` line, not the line before it.

Comment: You can also just write `line = ",".join(map(str, datalist))`, which would avoid the issue in the first place (and reveal that you probably want to reset `datalist` each time through the loop).

Comment: thank you very much both of you for your input, great help :) Not sure if I need to open another question but I'm also stuck on trying to add a Registration Number for each person when they are added. I was thinking it should be something like list.count(X)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong here.

As Patrick Haugh points out above, `map()` returns a map, not a list, and so doesn't have an `.append()` method. You can solve this by converting the map object in a list as he mentions: `datalist = list(map(str, datalist))`

There is also the fact that the Python lists don't have a `.count` attribute. Instead, you presumably want to know the length of the list, so you can just do `print(len(datalist))`.

Finally, there is a logical error: you will either need to write ONE line for each student at the end of the outer `while` loop, or else collect all the collected students and write them out at once. The former is much simpler. Just move the clearing of the `datalist` variable, inside the loop, to the top, rather than before it. Also note that since you are normalizing case with `moredata = moredata.upper()` and the bottom of the loop, you don't need to check for both cases at the top.

```
while (moredata=="Y"):
    datalist=[]
...
```